# could you any one tell me how to configure Hbase 0.92.1 with hadoop 1.0.1 on windows using cygwin

Tags: hbase

I have tried each and every step given on net to configure hbase on pseudo distributed mode but failed to run. It throws 'no class found' exception regarding zookeeper. I am new to hbase...please tell me steps to configure hbase..

Answer (score 0):

see Alan S's tutorial.  add an external zookeeper to hbase.

http://alans.se/blog/2010/hadoop-hbase-cygwin-windows-7-x64/